# Sunspot solr get field_names from searchable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, rubygems, sunspot-rails

how can i retrieve field list defined in searchable block ?

For example from:

```
Class Model < ...
searchable do 
string :field_string
int :field_int 
...
end 
end
```

get [:field_string, :field_int, ....]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `field_list` (@see [documentation](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#restrictions-and-field-list) and [field_list.rb](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/7c1d56c2d1d686c32fb9427bf1b68a9385a5b6ea/sunspot/lib/sunspot/query/field_list.rb)) :

```
field_list [:field_string, :field_int]
```

It is mapped to Solr [`fl`](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_6/common-query-parameters.html#fl-field-list-parameter) parameter :

> The fl parameter limits the information included in a query response
> to a specified list of fields.
> **The fields must be either `stored="true"` or `docValues="true"`**